# How can I play the content from another account on my new Xbox 360 console?

Tags: xbox-360

My brother bought a lot of games and game expansions a while ago on our XBOX 360, and I could play those as well. Now we have a new 360 and I can't play them on my account any more, while he can. Is there a way to re-install them without having to purchase them again?

Also: When I launched Skyrim once on his account and then switched back to mine, I could play the expansions, but when I came back to play the next day I couldn't, and logging in on his account no longer worked.

Comment: Did you have separate accounts when you shared a console?

Comment: I believe that the Skyrim issue may be down to you doing this when connected to Xbox Live (it may work when on Live, but not when offline)

Comment: @Ben These questions are clearly not the same. This account deals with multiple accounts and games; the other question asks about a single game, on a single account.

Answer (score 2):

You were able to play his content previously because the Xbox 360 uses a license system that is bound to the console.

Your brother will need to do a license transfer to the new console:

- Sign into the new Xbox with your brother's account
- Go to settings, and then select Account
- Go to Your Billing Options and select Licence Transfer

You will need to redownload the games again in some cases (this will download the new license details per game).

If your brother still uses the old console he won't see any difference as long as he plays his games whilst connected to Xbox Live.  If he disconnects he will not be able to use some of the content (if he is mid-game, he will get a 10 minute countdown before the game automatically closes).  Note that this refers to download content such as DLC and games on demand titles.  Playing from disk is fine.

There is a cool-down period for license transfering.  Currently, you need to wait 4 months between each transfer.

You can find more information from Xbox's official site:

[Xbox 360 DRM Details](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-360/store/download-content#4bfe6e94afb74c25ae8402012357759b)